# Rails upload CSV file, convert to JSON, and show in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, csv

I'm using Rails to upload a CSV file, send to my upload controller, convert to JSON, and send to a view.

I can't seem to correctly convert CSV to JSON. Let's say I have the following csv file:

```
'First','Second','Third','Fourth',
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8
```

How do I turn it into:

```
[{key:'anything', values:
[{'First': 1, 'Second':2, 'Third':3, 'Fourth':4},
{'First': 5, 'Second':6, 'Third':7, 'Fourth':8}]
}]
```

Thanks.